# Does 'begin transaction' with label prevent rollback all nested procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, rollback

If I have 3 procedures, one inside the other, I know that commit and rollback work like this:

[image]

If I put a label for each tansaction, does the rollback only rolls back to the previous procedure? like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SQL Server documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx):

> ROLLBACK TRANSACTION without a savepoint_name or transaction_name rolls back to the beginning of the transaction. **When nesting transactions, this same statement rolls back all inner transactions to the outermost BEGIN TRANSACTION statement**. In both cases, ROLLBACK TRANSACTION decrements the @@TRANCOUNT system function to 0. ROLLBACK TRANSACTION savepoint_name does not decrement @@TRANCOUNT.

Note the part I've emphasised. Unless you specify the name of an outer transaction, a rollback will only affect the innermost transaction.

Comment: If you have a follow up question, then you should [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) another one :)

Comment: I will be able to make another question just in 4 days hehehe

Comment: Yes thank you... now I have more reputation hehehe.. I came up with the other question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653937/rollback-at-stored-procedure-vs-rollback-at-c-sharp-code)