# Rollback at stored procedure vs rollback at C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I have a procedure Proc1 that calls another procedure Proc2, and both with "BEGIN TRANSCTION"
If i get an error at the second procedure, it will rollback both procedures. OK!

But inside my C# code, i have also this

```
...
   dbCommand.Transaction.Commit();
                dbCnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (dbCommand.Transaction != null)
                    **dbCommand.Transaction.Rollback();**
                if (dbCnn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    dbCnn.Close();

                throw ex;
            }
```

Does "dbCommand.Transaction.Rollback();" knows which transaction I am talking about? And if I have two transactions ate the same procedure, without label, will it be a problem for C# rollback the right transaction?

Comment: There is no such thing as "two transactions" - you can BEGIN TRANSACTION all you like, and you can get @@TRANCOUNT to be 500 if you like, but if you perform one ROLLBACK, they all roll back. Personally, I keep the transaction control inside the stored procedure - I have seen very few cases where the C# app needs to get involved with that at all.

Answer (score 3):

> Does "dbCommand.Transaction.Rollback();" knows which transaction I am
>   talking about?

No. It also does not care. It rolls back the transaction that is wrapping everything on connection level. Everything inside is part of this transaction.

> And if I have two transactions ate the same procedure, without label,
>   will it be a problem for C# rollback the right transaction?

You can not have two transactions. Transactions form a hierarchy. The code above rolls back the whole top level connection level transaction. Every other transaction you open in a sstored procedure is part of this transaction.

Comment: Sorry, I am a little confused now. The thing is, I can not or I should not put 2 transactions at sql server code? Because I created an example here with 2 tansactions inside a proc and it worked

Comment: You can. Whether it makes sense is your problem (the code does not care). There are fringe business cases for many things.

Answer (score 1):

As you defined the Transaction in C# code, there is not requirement to add Transaction in SQL Code. if anything goes wrong in SQL Code that will handle by C# Transaction, and rollback otherwise commit.

Comment: But with a try-catch inside the sql code, it will catch an error at the moment that it occurs, so it will prevent the rest of the sql to be executed. If I let c# handle the rollback, does it also stop the query or it will rollback just after the end of procedure (when sql return result to c#)

Comment: As Error occurred in SQL code, It will return to c# code, then in TransactionScope based on the Success or Failure you have to commit or rollback the C# transaction. Suppose, you have three different SQL commands which needs to executed  sequential from c# code. then Open the TransactionScope() with sqlconnection in C#, then Fire first sql command , suppose successfully executed  this sql command then based on the return value here either true/false and then if success then fire next command or rollback C# TransactionScope().